# no data in call to 'boot' in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns. The first column contains categories such as "System 1", "System 2", and the second column has numbers that represent the 0's and 1's. Please see below :

For example:

| SYSTEM | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 0 | 1 |
| S1 | 1 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |
| S2 | 0 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |

I have this code in R to run Bootstrap 95% CI for mean
function to obtain mean from the data (with indexing).

Here is my code :

```
m <- 1e4; n <- 5
set.seed(42)
df2 <- data.frame(SYSTEM=rep(c('S1', 'S2'), each=n/2), matrix(sample(0:1, m*n, replace=TRUE), m, n))
names(df2)[-1] <- paste0('Q', 1:n)
```

My code gives me this an error

Comment: Well, since you pass `"s1"` as the `questions_` argument, and then run the code `filter(Q1 == questions_)`, so `filter(Q1 == "s1)`, and from your picture of the data `Q1` is always 1 or 0, never equal to the string `"s1"`, your first `filter` line returns 0 rows and indeed you are passing no data (a 0-row data frame) to your `reportCI` function.

Comment: I made several changes, but it doesn't work  @gergor thomas . I'm hoping to help me to rewrite the function to produce the answer. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is. What do you hope to do with `filter(Q1==questions_)`? Because the way you are using it, `citext(system = "Q1", questions_ = "s1")` turns into `filter(Q1 == "s1")`  and that removes all the rows from your data. Your code will work a little bit better if you delete all those `filter` lines, but I assume you put them there for some reason... what is the reason?

Comment: I see you continue to edit the question, but you're not addressing my questions. I'm assuming that `df2` is the data frame your code seems to call `all` inside the `citext` function--if I'm wrong about that, please correct me and provide a sample of `all` as well. If I'm right, then you need to explain what your code is attempting to do, because the first lines you run `f_tmp <- all%>%  filter(Q1==questions_)%>% ...` remove all the data, resulting in a 0-row data frame. This is the root of your problem. I don't know what you're trying to do with that code, which makes it impossible to help.