# R: How to modify my code to group by then loop over all columns at once

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns. The first column contains categories such as "System 1", "System 2", and the second column has numbers that represent the 0's and 1's. Please see below :

For example:

| SYSTEM | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 0 | 1 |
| S1 | 1 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |
| S2 | 0 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |

I have this code in R to run Bootstrap 95% CI for mean
function to obtain mean from the data (with indexing).

Here is my code:

```
m <- 1e4
n <- 5
set.seed(42)
df2 <- data.frame(SYSTEM=rep(c('S1', 'S2'), each=n/2), matrix(sample(0:1, m*n, replace=TRUE), m, n))
names(df2)[-1] <- paste0('Q', 1:n)



set.seed(0)
library(boot)


#define function to calculate fitted regression coefficients
coef_function <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] #allows boot to select sample
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d) #fit regression model
  return(coef(fit)) #return coefficient estimates of model
}

#perform bootstrapping with 2000 replications
reps <- boot(data=df2, statistic=coef_function, R=2000, formula=Q1~Q2)

#view results of boostrapping
reps

#calculate adjusted bootstrap percentile (BCa) intervals
boot.ci(reps, type="bca", index=1) #intercept of model
boot.ci(reps, type="bca", index=2) #disp predictor variable
```

Result should be :

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df2, statistic = coef_function, R = 2000, formula = Q1 ~ 
    Q2)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original   bias    std. error
t1*    0.600  0.00082       0.074
t2*   -0.073 -0.00182       0.099
> boot.ci(reps, type="bca", index=1) #intercept of model
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 2000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = reps, type = "bca", index = 1)

Intervals : 
Level       BCa          
95%   ( 0.45,  0.74 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> boot.ci(reps, type="bca", index=2) #disp predictor variable
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 2000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = reps, type = "bca", index = 2)

Intervals : 
Level       BCa          
95%   (-0.26,  0.13 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

Here I'm only using Q1 and Q2. I also didn't use group by.

I don't know where if this possible to do for groups and columns at once.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If 'Q1' is the response variable, we may group by 'SYSTEM', then loop `across` the columns 'Q2' to 'Q5', create the formula from the column name (`cur_column()`) with 'Q1' in `reformulate` and pass it on to `boot`

```
library(boot)
library(dplyr)
out <- df2 %>% 
    group_by(SYSTEM) %>%
    summarise(across(Q2:Q5, 
   ~ list(boot(cur_data(), statistic = coef_function, R = 2000,
      formula = reformulate(cur_column(), response = 'Q1')))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  SYSTEM Q2     Q3     Q4     Q5    
  <chr>  <list> <list> <list> <list>
1 S1     <boot> <boot> <boot> <boot>
2 S2     <boot> <boot> <boot> <boot>
```

If we extract the column, the output will be

```
> out$Q2
[[1]]

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = cur_data(), statistic = coef_function, R = 2000, 
    formula = reformulate(cur_column(), response = "Q1"))


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1* 0.48025529 -0.0001032709  0.01019634
t2* 0.02355538  0.0003813531  0.01412119

[[2]]

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = cur_data(), statistic = coef_function, R = 2000, 
    formula = reformulate(cur_column(), response = "Q1"))


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1* 0.49564873 -0.0002947112 0.009942382
t2* 0.01850984  0.0003610360 0.013914520
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. First the code is working, but it's empty as you show and I'm not sure why. Second here is the errors  "All values of t are equal to  NA \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"
NULL
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `t0`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `t`. 
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA. I updated my question to include how the results should look like

Comment: Thank you @akrun. It works now when I add $ for each column. My question is the response part in the code, I believe there is a better way to do this instead of changing it manually or copying it multiple times ,my question how to do that?. I also  did I understand we only perform bootstrapping with 2000 replications, but we didnt not calculate the 95% confidence interval yet then my question is how to do that. Thank you again

Comment: @akrun if you wouldn't mind [closing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73788885/903061) as a duplicate of the copy you've answered here, I think that would be appropriate. (I already voted to close for a different reason, so can't do it myself.)

Comment: Oops, I meant [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73779135/903061), but looking more carefully now it seems like OP refined the question here, so it's not fully a dupe.